# Solve for x in the given fig.

Tags: circles

Find the radius of smaller circle if radius of bigger circle is 14 cm[image: circle on a graph with perpendicular tangents]

[image: i tried this]

i tried this for solving

Comment: I tried to use pythagoras theorem and got a cofusing ans

Comment: What was the answer? Please edit your original post and show your steps.

Comment: Hint: The circle's radius is less than $3.66$, because the area between the circle and the two lines has an area of $(28^2 - 196*\pi)/4$, or around $42.06$.

Comment: @visheshdas Are the two lines perpendicular?

Comment: Yups both are perpendicular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Using two Pythagoras, we get

$$14^2+14^2=(14+2x+ED)^2$$

and

$$x^2+x^2=(x+ED )^2$$

this gives
$$14^2+14^2=(14+x+x\sqrt {2})^2$$

and $$x=14 (3-2\sqrt {2}) $$

Comment: You are leaving length ED in above fig

Comment: Yps now its corrrect b

Comment: But how 2 solve for x further

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Where did you get ${2.14}^2$ from?

Comment: It looks too much like 2.14 squared, a better way to express this would be $(2)(14)^2$

Comment: @TobyMak just above you have$ 14^2+14^2$

Comment: Never mind, it might be just my opinion but its hard to tell this if the context is not given.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what @Salahamam_Fatima answered, the equation actually should be: $$14^2+14^2 = (14+x+EC)^2.$$
If we construct a line from $C$ to the other unlabelled tangent left of $C$ (call it $T_1$), and also label the tangent below $C$ $T_2$, $\angle T_1 E T_2$ is defined to be a right angle (OP said two lines were perpendicular in comments). Additionally, the two tangents are perpendicular to the centre by the tangent to a circle rule, so $ET_1CT_2$ is a square.

Following this, CE is the diagonal of a right angled triangle, so by Pythagoras's theorem, that length is $\sqrt {x^2+x^2}$ or $\sqrt {2} x$.

Now, the equation becomes: $$14^2+14^2 = (14+x+\sqrt {2} x)^2$$
= $$392 = 196 + 28\sqrt2 x + 2\sqrt2 x^2 + 3x^2$$
= $$ (3+2\sqrt2) x^2 + (28\sqrt2) x + (196) = 0$$
= $$ x = 42 - 28\sqrt2.$$

Comment: what do  i consider the solution in the second fig right or wrong??

Comment: It's wrong from what I can tell of the picture.

Comment: Where was i mistaken?? It all seems right to me

Comment: How do you know that EC is $14(\sqrt(2)-1)(n)$? What is $n$?

Comment: As EB =14{(2^1/2)-1}

Comment: And CB is x so EC =EB-CB=14{(2^1/2)-1}-X

Comment: $EB$ is $14\sqrt2- 14$, because $AB = 14$.

Comment: In short, when proofwriting DO NOT skip steps. More often than not your brain will miss out a number of variable and that will affect everything after that mistake.

Comment: Kk now i would make sure about it

Comment: But what about my ans??

Comment: Nice attempt though! Sometimes one number can ruin everything1

Comment: Read my post carefully and see if you can find any mistakes.

Comment: Another approach similar to what you did is to let $ED = (14\sqrt2)) - (14\sqrt2 - 14 - 2x)$, or $(AE) - (AB-BD)$ and work from there.

Comment: I think Salahamam_Fatima  approch is somewhat correct

Comment: It's very questionable — he pulls this number (${2.14}^2$) seemingly out of nowhere and skips steps. In my opinion, it's quite hard to follow what he does.

Comment: @visheshdas We should probably move this discussion to chat, there's too many comments.